# How to write parameterized functions in LilyPond?

Tags: lilypond

The LilyPond code below creates two notes, including their names on top and the corresponding fingering chart for saxophone.

```
\version "2.22.0"
#(print-keys-verbose 'saxophone)
#(set-global-staff-size 38)
\score{
    \relative {
        \textLengthOn
        d'1_\markup {
            \woodwind-diagram
            #'saxophone
            #'((cc . (one two three four five six))
               (lh . ())
               (rh . ()))
        }^\markup{D}
        e1_\markup {
            \woodwind-diagram
            #'saxophone
            #'((cc . (one two three four five))
               (lh . ())
               (rh . ()))
        }^\markup{E}
    }
}
```

[image: example output from LilyPond sample code]

I have the feeling that LilyPond uses something like Lisp syntax, but I'm more a Python person.

I want to write multiple constructs like that for each note (that I know currently), and I wonder how to create a function to reuse that code by just giving parameters in it; e.g., `note` (`d` in the example), `notename` (`D` in the example) and something for the `fingers` (`one two three four five six`).

Comment: LilyPond uses the [Scheme](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/extending/scheme-tutorial) programming language

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fragment you wrote could be spelled as

```
\version "2.22.0"
#(print-keys-verbose 'saxophone)
#(set-global-staff-size 38)
mydiag =
#(define-music-function (note notename fingers)
  (ly:pitch? markup? symbol-list?)
  #{
    $note 1_\markup {
      \woodwind-diagram
      #'saxophone
      #`((cc . ,fingers)
     (lh . ())
     (rh . ()))
     }^\markup #notename
    #})


\score {
  \relative {
    \textLengthOn
    \mydiag d' "D" one,two,three,four,five,six
    \mydiag e "E" one,two,three,four,five
  }
}
```

There may be some different requirements of yours that require additional changes, but that's sort of how it could be done.